# How to use SendKeys function on a rich Text Editor using protractor?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

In My Application there is a `textbox`, and when we click on the `Textbox` a **rich text box** appears,now we have to type some text in it . How this can be achieved using `Protractor`.

Here is the `HTML` Code:

```
<div class="span10 ckeditable editable-click cke_editable cke_editable_inline 
            cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders cke_focus" 
            contenteditable="true" 
            data-pk="102" data-name="RISK_FACTORS_HTML" 
            data-entity="MANAGERSTRATEGY_THESIS"
            tabindex="0" spellcheck="false" style="position: relative;" role="textbox" 
            aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor3" 
           title="Rich Text Editor, editor3" aria-describedby="cke_214">
    <p>
    <br type="_moz"/>
    </p>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: here is the HTML code
div class="span10 ckeditable editable-click cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders cke_focus" contenteditable="true" data-pk="102" data-name="RISK_FACTORS_HTML" data-entity="MANAGERSTRATEGY_THESIS" tabindex="0" spellcheck="false" style="position: relative;" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor3" title="Rich Text Editor, editor3" aria-describedby="cke_214">
<p>
<br type="_moz"/>
</p>

Comment: Please edit your question and include the HTML there! Also remove the code-syntax from the first line of your question...

Comment: Added the HTML in the question

Comment: Isn't `element(RICH_TEXT_BOX_LOCATOR).sendKeys("send_your_text");` working? If it's not working, then what error do you get when you use it?

Answer (score 0):

If your html is complete, then the problem could be that sendkeys only works on certain elements (input, textarea...). Instead of send keys you may want to try changing the text or inner html of the paragraph.

To test my theory do the following:

1.open your page in chrome or firefox
2.add some text
3. open webdeveloper, firebug...and see where the text you added was appended to